# DocuSign REST API DELETE method requires a body

Tags: docusignapi, servicenow

For example to remove a member from a signing group you call:

```
/restapi/v2/accounts/1686083/signing_groups/{groupId}/users
```

and provide:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "userName": "sample string 1",
            "email": "sample string 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

as the body

But my REST object (in ServiceNow) does not allow me to provide a body when I'm using the delete method.  Am I just stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any another way to remove the user from a SigningGroup using API. You can try to update the user in a Signing group to a Dummy Email so that original user will not get email for signing. And once in a while DS Admin can go to WEBApp and manually delete it, if Service now is not allowing DS API delete operation with a body.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RestMessageV2 in ServiceNow scripted Outbound REST, there's a `setRequestBody` method you can use to set the request body as a string:

[Example in the docs here](https://docs.servicenow.com/app_store/dev_portal/API_reference/RESTMessageV2/reference/r_RMV2-setRequestBody_String_body.html)

```
var sm = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2("Update user","post"); 
var body = "{ ...Message body content... }";
sm.setRequestBody(body);
```